# Game Crashes after applicationWillResignActive is called more than once

Tags: ios, swift, crash, sprite-kit

so when a user receives a text or goes into notification center or leaves the app a function called pauseGame() should be run, it works fine the first time but if someone was receive another text or go into notification center again then the app will crash, my question is why does it work the first time but crash the second? I think it has something to do with the timers but could you please look at my code, i have been googling for ever and this is my last resort! Thank you all!! (Also this code works fine on ios 9 and works every time but the problem is on ios 8)

Here is the function called when user goes into the background

```
  func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    print("Reply to Text or Notification Center or Multitasking")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("pauseGame", object: self)
}
```

Here is my pause function

```
func pauseGame() {
    if(paused == false) {
        //STOPS UPDATE AND MOVEMENT OF NODES
        if (gameOver == false) {

            spawnTopTimer.invalidate()
            spawnBottomTimer.invalidate()
            spawnLeftTimer.invalidate()
            spawnRightTimer.invalidate()
            scoreTimer.invalidate()


            paused = true
            pauseScreenActive = true

            player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = colisionType.Enemy.rawValue
            player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = colisionType.Player.rawValue
            player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = colisionType.Player.rawValue

            //RESETS NODES TO VISABLE
            pauseBtn.hidden = true
            screenContainer.hidden = false
            resumeBtn.hidden = false
            homeBtn.hidden = false
            highscoreLabel.hidden = false
            currentScoreLabel.hidden = false
            pauseLabel.hidden = false


            //PAUSE SCREEN NODES
            screenContainer.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width , height: self.frame.size.width)
            screenContainer.alpha = 0.8
            screenContainer.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2)
            screenContainer.zPosition = 900

            pauseLabel.text = "PAUSED"
            pauseLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height*0.69)
            pauseLabel.fontSize = 60
            pauseLabel.zPosition = 999

            resumeBtn.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 80)
            resumeBtn.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height*0.6)
            resumeBtn.zPosition = 999

            homeBtn.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 80)
            homeBtn.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height*0.45)
            homeBtn.zPosition = 999

            currentScoreLabel.text = "Current Score: " + String(score-1)
            currentScoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height*0.33)
            currentScoreLabel.fontSize = 40
            currentScoreLabel.zPosition = 999

            if(highscore == 0) {
                highscoreLabel.text = "Highscore: " + String(0)
            } else {
                highscoreLabel.text = "Highscore: " + String(highscore-1)
            }
            highscoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height*0.26)
            highscoreLabel.fontSize = 40
            highscoreLabel.zPosition = 999
        }
    }
}
```

here is my notifier

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("pauseGame"), name: "pauseGame", object: nil)
```

and here is the code that resumes the game after

```
if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == resumeBtn {
            if(pauseScreenActive == true) {
            //HIDE PAUSE SCREEN
            screenContainer.hidden = true
            resumeBtn.hidden = true
            homeBtn.hidden = true
            highscoreLabel.hidden = true
            currentScoreLabel.hidden = true
            pauseBtn.hidden = false
            pauseLabel.hidden = true
            player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = colisionType.Player.rawValue
            player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = colisionType.Enemy.rawValue
            player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = colisionType.Enemy.rawValue
            spawnTopTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ySpeed, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnTop"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            spawnBottomTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(ySpeed, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnBottom"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            spawnLeftTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(xSpeed, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnLeft"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            spawnRightTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(xSpeed, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnRight"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            print("Resume Speed with xValue: " + String(xSpeed) + " and yValue " + String(ySpeed))
            scoreTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("scoreCalculator"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            paused = false
            pauseScreenActive = false
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue might be in your GameScene. If you are registering your GameScene to receive NSNotifications, you also need to remove the registration as multiple registrations can cause crashes.

Try including `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` in the `willMoveFromView:(SKView *)view` method.

Answer (score 0):

YES!!!! That worked i had to change it to swift which was

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
```

but it fixed my crashes! Thank you so much i have been stuck in this for days :) <3 Big Ups to you sir!!